# Get a View's Width (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So you can get the width and height of the UIScreen as follows...

```
public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}

public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

But how can you get the width and height of a UIView?

Comment: While qtongo has already provided you with a good answer, you should get into the habit of doing as much research on your own before looking for somebody else to answer your questions. The `width` and `height` of a view are very basic properties that are really easy to find.

Comment: Honestly, I spent a while looking for the answer and tried a lot of different things.  If you search on Stack Overflow you will see there is nothing on this topic for Swift and a ton of posts for Android.  I thought it would be nice to have a simple post for people who searched for it in future and couldn't find it rather than something overly complicated going into all the different approaches I took.  How would you have gone about finding something simple like this in future if you weren't as experienced as you are now?

Comment: I don't agree with how many people are fast to assume how much research someone did.  Just because one person found it quickly with their default research methods, doesn't mean someone else will find it with a different research method and equal or greater effort. 
@Ben, the answer is the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview).  I recommend starting there before stack overflow.

Comment: Swift is very frustrating as it iterates constantly, so finding anything accurate is difficult. So sometimes inquiries need to be made as what research there is, is largely worthless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
extension UIView {
    public var viewWidth: CGFloat {
        return self.frame.size.width
    }

    public var viewHeight: CGFloat {
        return self.frame.size.height
    }
}
```